# Display only pictures taken by me

Tags: ios, photos.app, shortcuts-app

With iOS13, `Camera Roll` was removed from the `Photos` app, inexplicably. Pictures taken are now assigned to the `Recents` Album.

However, this Album also contains pictures/media from all sorts of sources (screenshots, whatsapp images, airdropped images, downloads, ...).

How can I display (or create a folder of, or otherwise separate) only photos/videos I took on this phone? I.e. how can I see my `Camera Roll`?